# Detach debugger in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

In Android Studio, how do you detach the debugger once it's connected and debugging a running app?

In Eclipse, the icon looked like this [image].

I've been disconnecting the USB cable but that seems like a brute method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer is the Close button. As of Android Studio v3.4 it's a red square block icon (previously was a red X).

It turns out I couldn't see it because it was hidden under the more >> icon.

Comment: in `Run` section (Alt + 4). you can use Ctrl + F4 as shortcut instead

Comment: But this stops the app from running as well. There is no easy way to just disconnect and keep the app running.

Comment: I think it's a bug. I've noticed sometimes it kills the app and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: On Android Studio 2.2, it seems to work better: The "Stop" button (red square) will disconnect the debugger without stopping the app, as long as you use "Attach Debugger to Android Process".

Comment: Has this been removed in 3.3?

Comment: It's now a red stop button.

Comment: An alternative is to mute breakpoints, but that doesn't answer this question.

Comment: This is not a solution at all, as it kills the app altogether.

Answer (score 7):

*I'm writing this assuming that Android Studio uses the same convention as IntelliJ IDEA*.

Click "close" (the button with the red ✕ in the debug panel):

[image]

You will be prompted. Choose whether to disconnect and/or terminate:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of Android Studio, the (X) Close button in the sidebar no longer exists.  If that is your case and you want to detach the debugger from Android Studio, you can tap the "X" in the tab at the top of the debugging window that says "Android Debugger (XXXX)"

[image]

Comment: It's the red square below the pause button.

Answer (score 0):

In case the **X** (Close) button is not shown because it is collapsed in the toolbar:

1. Resize the Debugger window to see the **X** button

OR

2. Press **CTRL + F4** (CMD + F4 on MAC).

OR

3. Right click on the Debugger Tab and select **Close**.

Then press **Disconnect** in the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

On android studio 3.3.1 I also can't find an easy way to disconnect the emulator. I've resorted to the terminal command `adb kill-server` (use `adb start-server` to start it again)